# How to fetch the value of integer array in java using REST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have created a controller to fetch a json object. I have tried using a rest client but I am getting the null value in integer array. Below is the request object class and the json request. If any one knows how to retrieve the value of the integer array, I have tried int[], List but I got the same null value.
See my json and request object.

Request JSON:

```
    {
    "allUser":false,
    "userIds": [622,46]
    }
```

Request Object Class:

```
public class restRequest {
    boolean allUser;
    Integer []  userIds;

    public boolean isallUser() {
        return allUser;
    }
    public void setallUser(boolean allUser) {
        this.allUser = allUser;
    }
    public Integer[] getUserIds() {
        return userIds;
    }
    public void setUserIds(Integer[] userIds) {
        this.userIds = userIds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here I'm using Gson to convert the json to the corresponding object and you can download the jar from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2/gson-2.2.2.jar)or add the maven dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

following is code snippet

```
public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "{\"allUser\":false,\"userIds\": [622,46]}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        RestRequest restRequest = gson.fromJson(data, RestRequest.class);
        System.out.println(restRequest);
    }
}
```

and the RestRequest class is as follows:

```
public class RestRequest {

    boolean allUser;
    Integer[] userIds;

    // getters & setters methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("RestRequest [allUser=");
        builder.append(allUser);
        builder.append(", userIds=");
        builder.append(Arrays.toString(userIds));
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

and the final result is `RestRequest [allUser=false, userIds=[622, 46]]`